# Problem with Bind Property for Multiselect element

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

My goal is to create a filterlist where you can choose which schooldays you want to show.

Now I connected the `select` element via `BindProperty` to my variable `school` (see C#-Code below). Everything works fine until I decide not to select anything.

So for example I have previously selected Monday and saved it as a filterlist. After that I decide to change it and uncheck Monday again. Now all the itmes in the Multiselect element are unchecked. However when I click on save. The value of Monday is still stored in the variable `school`.
Otherwise if I uncheck Monday but check Tuesday and save the list, the variable has change to the value of Tuesday.

How can I empty my variable with the BindProperty?

C#

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int[] school { get; set; }
```

HTML-Code

```
<div class="form-group col s3">
    <label asp-for="school" class="control-label">Schultage</label>
    <select asp-for="school" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.SchoolDays" multiple > 
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't get the problem. Do you want to select empty item and update it?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to delete the selection. So the selection is empty and after saving the variable should be empty too. But somehow the variable still has the value of the previous selection.

Comment: Can you try make your school variable as nullable?

Comment: Hi @Sevi, it also works fine on my side. How do you post the select to backend? Could you pls share more details about the html code and backend code? Besides, did you use any third party library for this multiselect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very strange, in the frontend the value of the select element is empty, but in the backend it wont save as empty.

So I solved it by setting the variable `school` in the `Post Methode`, by using the value of the frontend element. Instead of using the BindProperty.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group col s3">
        <label asp-for="school" class="control-label">Schultage</label>
        <select  asp-for="school" name="schoolDaySelect" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.SchoolDays" multiple ></select>
</div>
```

C#

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id , int[] schoolDaySelect)
{
    school = schoolDaySelect;
```